# How to recursively iterate over Swift Syntax with SwiftSyntax library?

Tags: swift, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to iterate in my code over the Swift AST like this, finding the struct keyword.

```
private func recursion(node: Syntax) -> String {
    for child in node.children {
        if let tokenKind = (child as? TokenSyntax)?.tokenKind, tokenKind == .structKeyword {
       // if type(of: child) == StructDeclSyntax.self {
            print ("yeah")
        }

        recursion(node: child)
    }
}

let input = """
        public struct cmd_deleteEdge<E: VEdge> : EdgeCommand {
            public var keyEquivalent = KeyEquivalent.none
            public let title = "Delete Edge"
            public let id = "deleteEdge"
            public let toolTip = "Delete selected Edge"
            public let icon = Icon.delete
            
            //receivers
            public let edge: E
            
            public init(edge: E) {
                self.edge = edge
            }
            
            public func execute() throws -> ActionResult {
                edge.deleteYourself()
                return .success("deleted edge")
            }
        }
"""

public func convert(structText: String) throws -> String  {
    let sourceFile = try SyntaxParser.parse(source: structText)
    let result = recursion(node: Syntax(sourceFile))
    return result
}


try convert(structText: input)
```

It just simply doesn't work, I never reach the "Yeah" (which means I cannot do anything useful during the recursion).

I find this library very confusing. Would anyone have a good UML diagram explaining how it really works?

Before you tell me, yes I know I could use a Visitor, but I want to understand how it works by myself.

Comment: There’s no actual recursion here

Comment: very valid point, Alexander. Now fixed ;-) Result is the same.

Comment: I don't have the development environment to set up and run this code right now. Could you include some debug output that helps people understand this program behaviour more easily at-a-glance? My first intuition is that if nothing is getting printed, your "filtering" behavior `(the `if let`) is incorrect. I would suggest starting off by printing every node with some diagnostic info (e.g. node type, line in source file, etc.), and then see what the raw data looks like before starting to filter for  `structKeyword`

Comment: That is my problem. I don't understand the library structure/data types and cannot convert between the types

Comment: Oh wow I really botched the formatting of my last comment, ah well. Yeah the documentation of the library ... sucks (doesn't exist?). I would recommend you `print(type(of: node), node)` etc. to see what exactly you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SyntaxProtocol` for iterating all items in AST and then use its `_syntaxNode` public property to make a target syntax, e.g.:

```swift
import SwiftSyntax
import SwiftSyntaxParser

func recursion(node: SyntaxProtocol) {
    if let decl = StructDeclSyntax(node._syntaxNode) {
        print(decl.identifier)
    }
    node.children.forEach { recursion(node: $0) }
}

let code = """
struct A {}

class Some {
    struct B {}
}

func foo() {
    struct C {}
}
"""

let sourceFile = try SyntaxParser.parse(source: code)
recursion(node: sourceFile)
```

Outputs:

```
A 
B 
C
```

> NOTE: It is not recommended to retrieve `_syntaxNode`  property directly and you can use `Syntax(fromProtocol: node)` instead.

**SyntaxVisitor**

But the best approach is using Visitor pattern with `SyntaxVisitor` class to avoid recursion issues for large and complex files:

```swift
class Visitor: SyntaxVisitor {
    var structs = [StructDeclSyntax]()
    
    init(source: String) throws {
        super.init()
        let sourceFile = try SyntaxParser.parse(source: source)
        walk(sourceFile)
    }
    
    // MARK: - SyntaxVisitor
    
    override func visit(_ node: StructDeclSyntax) -> SyntaxVisitorContinueKind {
        structs.append(node)
        return .skipChildren
    }
}

let visitor = try Visitor(source: code)
visitor.structs.forEach {
    print($0.identifier)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it after trial & error and reviewing of the API.

```
private func recursion(node: Syntax) -> String {
    for child in node.children {
        if let token = TokenSyntax(child),  token.tokenKind == .structKeyword {
            print ("yeah")
        }
        recursion(node: child)
    }
    return node.description
}
```

This approach to identify the kind of the token works, and the print statement will be reached. Again, I do wonder how the class diagram for SwiftSyntax would look like.

Comment: I found out that instead of creating a TokenSyntax, I can as well directly `if let structDecl = StructDeclSyntax(child) { ...`. A conversion from a token to a StructDeclSyntax element wasn't possible.